# style considered harmful?

Tags: html, security

We have some code that removes "dangerous" attributes and tags from HTML.  I noticed that `style` is among the list of "dangerous" attributes.  What could be the risk from that attribute?

Comment: What is the basis of the code which does the removal?  Was it developed in house or by a standards committee (for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make things that are invisible or otherwise very deceptive using style sheets. For example, you could put a giant, invisible anchor link over the whole page so that when the user clicks on something, he's taken to an identical page on a server in Russia.

Answer (score 2):

In IE you can include `@behaviors` in there which can load little Javascripts.

With CSS3 you can also interject little bits of text, which could be dangerous depending on your website.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an example of a bug in MediaWiki](http://secunia.com/advisories/17074/) that creates a vulnerability based on inline style attributes.